# TypeError: Router.use() requires a middleware function but got a undefined problem in routeer

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Everyone I'm beginner in NODEJS I'm trying to do small chat app.I'm facing routing problem in user.js.

throw new TypeError('Router.use() requires a middleware function but got a ' + gettype(fn))
^

TypeError: Router.use() requires a middleware function but got a undefined

I have this code in my user.js

```
const { Router } = require('express');
const router = Router();


const  UserC  = require('../controllers/userControllers.js');

 router.get('/users', UserC.getUsers);
 router.post('/users', UserC.crreateUsers);
 router.get('/users/:id', UserC.getUser);

module.exports =  {
    routes: router
}
```

class index.js

```
const app = require('./app');
const confit = require('../config');
const userRoutes = require('./routes/user-router');
const rolesRoutes = require('./routes/roles-router.js');
const loginRoutes = require('./routes/login-router');
const takerServicios = require('./routes/takerServices-router');
const clienteAbogado = require('./routes/clienteAbogado-router');
const services = require('./routes/servicios-router');




app.use('/api', userRoutes.routes);
app.use('/api', rolesRoutes.routes);
app.use('/api', loginRoutes.routes);
app.use('/api', takerServicios.routes);
app.use('/api', clienteAbogado.routes);
app.use('/api', services.routes);



app.listen(app.get('port') );
app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
    console.log(err);
    res.status(err.status || 500).send(err.stack);
});
//console.log("hola servidor: ", app.get('port'));
```

class app.js

```
const express = require('express');
const morgan = require('morgan');
const exphbs = require('express-handlebars');
const helmet = require('helmet');
const path = require('path');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const db = require('../conection');
const cors = require('cors');
const multer = require('multer');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const serviceAccount = require('../serviceAccountKey');

const app = express();


// ------------------------------- INICIALIZAR FIREBASE ADMIN ------------------------

admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount)
})

const upload = multer({
    storage: multer.memoryStorage()
})
// ------------------------------- settings ------------------------------------------

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.engine('.hbs', exphbs({
    defaultLayout: 'main',
    extname: '.hbs'
}));

app.set('view engine', '.hbs');

// ---------------------------------------------------------------- middlewares ----------------------------------------------------------------

app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));
app.use(cors());

app.disable('x-powerd-by');
//app.use(bodyParser.json());
//app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));


// ---------------------------------------------------------------- routes ----------------------------------------------------------------

app.use(require('./routes/index'));

// ---------------------------------------------------------------- static files ----------------------------------------------------------------

app.get('/style.css', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/" + "style.css");
  });

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,"public")));
//app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));


 dbConnection = async () => {

    try {
        await db.connect();
        console.log('database online');
    } catch(err) {
        throw new Error(err);
    }
}

module.exports = app;
```

Comment: Can you post your `userControllers.js` code?

Answer (score 0):

In which line it crashes?
Indeed, the userControllers.js would be helpfully.

Maybe there is a typo?

```
router.post('/users', UserC.crreateUsers);
```

instead of

```
router.post('/users', UserC.createUsers);
```

For correctness, i would change the post route to singular: "createUser"
I think you just create one user with a single post.

BR
Patrick